# How to write in Django a custom management command which takes a URL as a parameter?

Tags: python, django, command

I am learning to write custom management commands in Django. I would like to write a command which would take a given URL as a parameter. Something like:

```
python manage.py command http://example.com
```

I've read a documentation, but it is not clear to me how to do this.
But I can write a command saying 'Hello World!';)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this:

create a file under `yourapp/management/commands/yourcommand.py` with the following content:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'A description of your command'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            '--url', dest='url', required=True,
            help='the url to process',
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        url = options['url']
        # process the url
```

then you can call your command with

```
python manage.py yourcommand --url http://example.com
```

and either:

```
python manage.py --help
```

or

```
python manage.py yourcommand --help
```

will show the description of your command and the argument.

if you don't want to name the argument (the `--url` part), like in your example, just read the url('s) form `args`:

```
def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for url in args:
        # process the url
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Good example. But the question only deals with one URL. So drop the '--' in front of add_argument and it'll work magically (well, thanks to [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags)).

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot! But I don't understand the last part (without --url) - what should be after:    for url in args:

Comment: @AlekSZ, that is up to you, there you process the URL given as argument.

Comment: perfectly explained